# qrcode !barcodeDetector.isOperational() mobile vision API

Tags: android

> **EDIT:** the problem is no more that the app doesn't work. I tried to execute it on Galaxy S7 and works well. Then in an Huawei Honor 6X and
>   it doesn't work.

I'm having some trouble developing QR code reader.
I created **view.java**:

```
package com.example.android.gpsv01;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;


public class view extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    CameraSource cameraSource;
    TextView txtResult;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(surfaceView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        txtResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //Istanzio l'oggetto barcodeDetector
        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                //Specifico quale barcode deve rilevare (ne esistono molti tipi)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                .build();
        if(!barcodeDetector.isOperational()) {
            txtResult.setText("Could not set up the detector!");
        }
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        //Aggiungo l'evento
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(view.this, new String []{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                        return;
                    }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(surfaceHolder);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }


            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                Log.e("********", "" + qrcodes.size());
                if(qrcodes != null && (qrcodes.size() > 0))
                {
                    String barcode = qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                    if (!barcode.isEmpty()) {
                        txtResult.setText(barcode);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

So, when I open this activity, It prompt to me **Could not set up the detector!**, and `qrcodes.size()` always return 0.

In my **AndroidManifest.xml** there are:

```
<activity
            android:name=".view"
            android:label="Check out your route" >
            //Necessario per leggere codici qr
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode" />
        </activity>
```

and

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In my **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.6.0'

    //Necessario per leggere codici qr
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
}
```

I didn't understand why, also because I followed step by step any Youtube tutorial. 
I don't know if it's relevant but, rarely, instead of 0, it prompt 
`void hw::COutMetaSplitBase::dump_thermal_meter(monitor_t): open  failed!`
Additionally my framing doesn't look like the real camera

Comment: Google's library for QRcode/Barcode scanning is best, still you can try removing final from your qrcodes definition.

Comment: I removed final from the qrcodes declaration... It is still not working

Comment: Try to go to device's permission settings and see if all permissions are getting granted successfully.

Comment: Yes. Camera and location (that isn't necessary here) are granted

Comment: and you checked what's return type of `getDetectedItems()`. Also can you show your logcat?

Comment: You mean this? [link](https://i.imgur.com/smJvBZc.png)